# Как заменить точку на пробел?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача век и год, вводится год, программа должна вывести век и год через пробел.

```
a = int(input())

print((a/100) if(a%100==1) else(a/100+1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать метод replace который заменяет все символы в строке на другой символ

```
a = int(input())
var = str((a/100) if(a%100==1) else(a/100+1)).replace(".", " ")
print(var)
```

Comment: Спасибо, но все равно почему-то только на 70 из 100

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка: при целочисленном делении должен получаться ноль, тогда век будет считаться правильно.

```
a = int(input())
if a%100==0:
    print(int(a/100), "00")
else:
    print(int(a//100 +1), a%100)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно пояснить что такое 00 в 3 строчке

Comment: а, все понял, спасибо